# Deserialize JSON from Firebase

Tags: c#, json, firebase

I have a JSON file from firebase that has a list of nodes with their own unique names, If possible I'd like to deserialize the contents all into a list just like a normal JSON array using Newtonsoft.Json like this:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    List<Card> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(json);
}
```

However Because of this JSON format from Firebase, each node has a unique name, is there any way to deserialize them like a normal JSON array without editing the format of the JSON using Newtonsoft.Json?

I can safely ignore the node name as I only need the contents of each objects and put them in a list.

```
{
  "131F78DB" : {
    "IDNumber" : "5526F",
    "Name" : "NAME1"
  },
  "19505EAD" : {
    "IDNumber" : "5132F",
    "Name" : "TEMPORARYHR10103"
  },
  "19539B6D" : {
    "IDNumber" : "10102",
    "Name" : "TEMPORARYHR10102"
  }
}
```

I will be working with large JSON files like this so if possible I'd like to avoid doing any manual string manipulation to remove the node names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize it as a `Dictionary` like this:

```cs
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Card>>(json);
```

That way you can still iterate over it like a `list`, it matches the format of the json, and you still have all the information available (even if you don't need the key values).

If you really want to have it as a list you could add `Select(x => x.Value).ToList()` to create a `List<Card>`.