# Firebase Json Deserialize with Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I need some help with understanding Firebase using with Xamarin

I follow this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/

But I get this error right now

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Delirium.Models.Drugs]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array

And I am confused why as I am following documentation on how to use Firebase with xamarin.

When I run the code, It connects to my Firebase and it successfully gets the data because it holds it in the debug and I can see all my info but it gets stuck and throws this error.

I am using this code :

**firebase helper is**

```
    FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("My database Url");

    public async Task<List<Drug>> GetAllDrugs()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Drugs")
          .OnceAsync<Drug>()).Select(item => new Drug
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
              ID = item.Object.ID
          }).ToList();
    }
```

and this is the other part, basically what I am doing is using a Listview and I want to get the data from my firebase and show it in a List view

```
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var drugs = await firebaseHelper.GetAllDrugs();
        drugList.ItemsSource = drugs;
    }
```

with XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="drugList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"></TextCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

and lastly this is the 'item' class

```
public class Drug
{
    public string AfterEffect { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ChemicalClass { get; set; }
    public string ComeUp { get; set; }
    public string ComeDown { get; set; }
    public string CommonNames { get; set; }
    public string Compound { get; set; }
    public string HighDose { get; set; }
    public string LowDose { get; set; }
    public string MediumDose { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PsychoactiveClass { get; set; } 
    public string Onset { get; set; }
    public string Peak { get; set; }
    public string TotalDuration { get; set; }
}
```

As for my Firebase, here is what one item looks like

[image]

And here is part of a very long error. What makes it long is it basically lists the entire database of 310 different drugs.

[image]

I have tried to use [Deserialize JSON from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785338/deserialize-json-from-firebase) as someone mentioned but I cant seem to make it work (or I'm not understanding)

Thanks for help :)

Comment: what is the definition of `Items`?

Comment: 1) Show the data you get back from Firebase. Then it will be easier to explain to you what the error message is saying, about how that data differs from the structure of the object you are deserializing to. 2) Is `Items` really the name of your class that describes a single item? Why isn't the class name `Item`? 3) Most importantly, The error message is talking about code that you are not showing. Show definition of object that matches type `Dictionary2[System.String,Delirium.Models.Drugs]'`. 4) Exactly what data from firebase are you expecting to go into `Drugs`? Show test data for a Drugs.

Comment: ... I mean, write test code that creates "hardcoded" data, and store that data into that `Dictionary[String, Drugs]`. So we can see what is supposed to happen. 5) Debug your deserialization step-by-step. Before you get firebase to work, prove to yourself that you know how to serialize/deserialize your data. Can you serialize one `Drugs`, then deserialize that into a `Drugs` object? Then, can you serialize an array `Drugs[]`, and deserialize that back into an array or list? Once you have code that does that, you should be able to get it to work with firebase.

Comment: Ok so I updated my code as it Actually is , I changed the "drugs" to drug as mentioned, I also added a screenshot of one of my Firebase Jsons. 

Now a small note to take into consideration if it's relevant is , some of my entries in the Json file don't have all things filled in, so for instance some might have "PsychoactiveClass" missing or some might have "Peak" time missing etc. 

Also the "parent" of the Firebase Json is "Drugs", though it shouldn't be relevant in this case because I know that the response is working :)

Comment: I also added a screenshot of the error, though It's really really long so I cannot paste it or screenshot it all because it basically lists all 310 drugs in my database in that format as shown above

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785338/deserialize-json-from-firebase

Comment: I Still cannot figure it out , I double triple checked that my class matches everything but I still don't understand. I tried to follow this tutorial 

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/

Comment: Maybe you could get the json string from your response,then deserialize it to your Drugs.